# How do I keep form data and add dom elements dynamically after postback?

Tags: jquery, dom, dynamic, postback

I use the following code to dynamically add or remove input fields with jQuery by simply copying the parent div:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
        var num = $('.clonedInput').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
        var newNum = new Number(num + 1);      // the numeric ID of the new input field being added

        // create the new element via clone(), and manipulate it's ID using newNum value
        var newElem = $('#input' + num).clone().attr('id', 'input' + newNum);

        // manipulate the name/id values of the input inside the new element
        newElem.children(':first').attr('id', 'author' + newNum).attr('name', 'author' + newNum).attr('value', 'enter a name');

        // insert the new element after the last "duplicatable" input field
        $('#input' + num).after(newElem);

        // enable the "remove" button
        $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', '');

        // business rule: you can only add 5 names
        if (newNum == 5)
            $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });

    $('#btnDel').click(function () {
        var num = $('.clonedInput').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
        $('#input' + num).remove();     // remove the last element

        // enable the "add" button
        $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', '');

        // if only one element remains, disable the "remove" button
        if (num - 1 == 1)
            $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });

    $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

Now basically What I want to do is, as soon as one of the maximum six input fields is filled out (onchange event ?), its value should automatically be saved in a hidden input field.

This should happen with each input field. The Values should be seperated by ';' and according to the amount of values inside the hidden input element it should - after a postback - add the exact amount of input fields int the dom with the above clone() function and also fill the values back in.

Because after each postback (if for example not all required fields have been filled out) it does not automatically add the (via jQuery) added input fields, which of course makes sense....

If there is a more simple method of how I could do this, I'd love to hear how, otherwise I would appreciate any help on this as I am clueless, especially with the seperation of the values.

**[edit]**

What I forgot to mention is, that I use c# .net and the hidden input field uses the **runat="server"** attribute.

**[edit 2]**

Additional info: I have this in a web form. With this form you can save "projects" on a website (data is stored in a database). These projects/articles can have multiple (max. 6) authors and that is when the jQuery comes in...The user can add up to 6 authors and as they are added to the dom dynamically by the user after the page has been loaded, they're not being automatically added after the form has been sent (postback) to the server. So I need to store the values of theses input fields, seperated from each other in order to still have the values after the postback, but also to add the by the user defined amount of author input fields. I hope this makes it more or less clear what I want to do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the reason for wanting to save the value in the hidden field? (I also presume this is webforms?)

Comment: because I have to know the values after the postback and I also have to know how many input fields were added in the dom and that I can find out by storing the values seperated by a semicolon for instance in a string so I can add these input fields including the values after the postback, otherwise they'll be gone.

And Yes, it's a web form.

Comment: The values in these input fields that get sent back to the server I presume are saved somewhere in a db? Can you not then have the server render the form from these values?

Comment: Ok to avoid misunderstandings read my second edit above...

Comment: Ok, so the values in these fields are just strings I presume (names of the authors). These fields need to be rendered by the server as all information will be lost on postback (as it's stateless). So once you post these values to the server, save them, then use them to render the page server side. (p.s. your life would be so much easier if you adopted mvc) :-)

Comment: Well, this is not entirely true...the information will not be lost. asp.net automatically saves them. The problem though are the jQuery added input fields...If they would stay, I wouldn't have a problem at all. As they do not stay, I have to do it this way and I can't do it serverside.

Comment: It needs to be done server side. In the code behind of your page, dynamically add the text boxes with their values to the form with the author info from the db.